# How to do work on the background in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am having problems while doing work in the background in Android. I need to do a http request every 5s in a app of my own use (won't publish the app). I've seem that since version O Android had put limitations on the operational system and I'm doing what is recomended, that is, I'm creating a foreground service with a persistent notification to run this task. It works fine with the screen on, and even with the app closed, but after a while if the phone is locked it enters the Doze mode and lock my requests until I turn the screen on again. I've tried to mess with the power savings configurations of my phone with no luck.

Anyone have faced that issue?

Preferably without FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).

I am doing it on Xamarin.Forms, but if you have some example in Java that's ok, I'll get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

Also you have to ask the user to put your app on the Battery_Optimization whitelist at runtime, like descriped [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby):

```
//check for ignoring battery optimization
PowerManager mPowerManager = (PowerManager) your_context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)

if (!mPowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimization(your_context.getPackageName())) {
    //ask for permission
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + your_context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

BUT your app is most likely not going to get approved by Google Play, when you try to release it to the PlayStore!
You should use FCM high-priority messages instead.

Comment: Ok, I've added the permission and still same behavior. I've manually entered the battery options for the appliction and turned off the battery optimizations. How to put the app on the whitelist, should it use the alarm manager? I won't publish the app to google play store, so no problems in that part. Can I do http requests after receiving the FCM messages? Because I've tried to use FCM to wake the device and continue the work and it just received the FCM message.

Comment: I edited my answer and added the java code to whitelist the app. Adding the permission alone doesn't do the trick, because you also have to whitelist the app.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't too many ways to do it on Android in nowadays.
Try to look at this [Google tutorial](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) and choose the right one.

Regarding the REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS permission, your app should fit these [conditions](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#exemption-cases).
You'll find more details here [android-doze-standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly if you need do a task every X seconds use an alarm broadcast:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

You just implement a receiver and you can perform the task. If you need it in a specific class implement the receiver as in inner class running on a new thread re-registering the alarm every time.